# No operator+ for std::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

It is possible to [append](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) multiple paths in a row using the `/` operator:

```
  std::filesystem::path p1{"A"};
  auto p2 = p1 / "B" / "C";
```

which is rather convenient. However, [concat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/concat) only offers `+=`:

```
  std::filesystem::path p1{"A"};
  auto p2 = p1 / "B" / "C" + ".d";   // NOT OK
```

This is pretty annoying, as I can't easily add extensions to the end of my paths. I have no choice but to write something like

```
  std::filesystem::path p1{"A"};
  auto p2 = p1 / "B" / "C";
  p2 += ".d";
```

Am I missing something? Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: Nope. There is no other way

Comment: @KamilCuk not possible with `const char[N]`, that would be `auto p2 = p1 / "B" / (std::string("C") + ".d");`

Comment: `("C" + ".d")` adds two `const char[2]`s

Comment: @KamilCuk a string literal like "A" is of type "const char[N]" and will be converted to "const char*" when using operator +, so you're adding two pointers with `"A"+"B"`

Comment: note that in practice, `"C"` will most likely also be a `std::filesystem::path`, so the second option won't work. The first one is bizarre, but should work. :)

Comment: sooo. `auto p2 = p1 / "B" / "C" += ".d";` or `auto p2 = p1 / "B" / (std::string() + "C" + ".d");` :D . Both of the these work in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b7oTYv). `note that in practice, "C" will most likely` Not in practice, in any case the result of `p1 / "B" / "C"` has type `std::filesystem::path`, so it's doing `+=` on it. Still, this is not an answer, as I do not know "the reason for this inconsistency".

Comment: For the reason, I guess someone will have to look into "the mailing list" or something similar. For being able to assign/ `+=` to rvalue there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461889/why-can-i-use-assignment-operator-on-begin-even-if-it-is-an-rvalue#comment115734027_65461889 . A `path()` call will help (`(path(a) += b)`) if the object inside is a lvalue.

Comment: @KamilCuk By "in practice", I meant, "in my real life application". This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit speculative, but I think the reason for this is that an `operator+` could be easily confused with `operator/`. This would then lead to bugs if used as follows

```
path p2{"/"};
auto p1 = p2 + "A" + "B";
// Wants /A/B, gets /AB
```

Using string literals makes the workaround nicer:

```
using namespace std::literals;
std::filesystem::path p1{"A"};
auto p2 = p1 / "B" / ("C"s + ".d");
```

Here, `"C"s` creates a `std::string` with content `C` and then we use `std::string`'s `operator+`. If the `"C"` part is itself already a path (otherwise you could just write `"C.d"` to begin with), you can do

```
std::filesystem::path p1{"A"}, c_path{"C"};
auto p2 = p1 / "B" / (c_path += ".d");
```

since `operator+=` returns the resulting object. (This is a bit wasteful but I can imagine that the compiler will optimize that).

Comment: You can simply `auto p2 = p1 / "B" / "C" += ".d"`; No parentheses necessary due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

If all what you need is to add extensions, you can also do this:

```
std::filesystem::path p1{"A"};
auto p2 = (p1 / "B" / "C").replace_extension(".d");
```

Answer (score 0):

I though maybe it was because std::string and const char * implicitly convert to std::filesystem::path. Here is some c++20 being very careful to avoid unwanted implicit conversions.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
template <typename T, typename U>
requires std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, std::filesystem::path> &&
    (!std::same_as<std::decay_t<U>, std::filesystem::path>) && 
        std::convertible_to<std::decay_t<U>, std::filesystem::path>
    inline std::filesystem::path
        operator+(const T &lhs, const U &rhs) {
    auto tmp = lhs;
    tmp += rhs;
    return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
requires std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, std::filesystem::path> ||
    std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, std::filesystem::directory_entry>
inline std::filesystem::path operator+(const std::filesystem::path &lhs,
                                       const T &rhs) {
    auto tmp = lhs;
    tmp += rhs;
    return tmp;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "aaa" + std::filesystem::path{"bbb"} << '\n';
    std::cout << "aaa"s + std::filesystem::path{"bbb"} << '\n';
    std::cout << std::filesystem::directory_entry{"aaa"} +
                     std::filesystem::path{"bbb"}
              << '\n';

    std::cout << std::filesystem::path{"aaa"} + "bbb" << '\n';
    std::cout << std::filesystem::path{"aaa"} + "bbb"s << '\n';
    std::cout << std::filesystem::path{"aaa"} +
                     std::filesystem::directory_entry{"bbb"}
              << '\n';

    std::cout << std::filesystem::path{"aaa"} + std::filesystem::path{"bbb"}
              << '\n';
    std::cout << std::filesystem::directory_entry{"aaa"} +
                     std::filesystem::directory_entry{"bbb"}
              << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such operator, but actually it's pretty easy to add such one on one's own; below is the *quick and dirty* variant coming along as a template (safer might be individual overloads matching those of `operator+=`, not going that fare here, though):

```
template <typename T>
std::filesystem::path operator+(std::filesystem::path path, T&& data)
// (accepting by value, we're going to modify!)
{
    path += std::forward<T>(data);
    return path;
}
```

Sure, no perfect forwarding necessary either, all operators of `path` accept by value or const reference anyway, but who knows if that changes any day…

If that's a good idea (see [n314159](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345656/n314159) [suspecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921927/1312382) it might have been avoided by C++ committee to prevent confusing it with the other operator) – well, abstaining from reasoning about…